# Radio Button in C#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, radio-button, postback

I am Doing Project On “*Online Railway Reservation System*” using `C# .net` as front End and `SQL Server` as backend.

In this project I have make one page for Train Inquiry in which I have provided Source and Destination City.

In this Page I had used two gridview, `Gridview1` and `Gridview2`:

- In `Gridview1` Trains table is binding.
- In `Gridview2` I had Seat table binding.

In `Gridview1` I have used Radio Button in template field and its `AutopostBack` property set to `true`.

If I set `Autopostback` property value of radio button `false` then I have not get Class value… So I have to set `Autopostback` property `true`. So when I am clicking radio button gridview data changed that should not happen so please anybody help me…

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: For a reason why are you doing postback for this one? And btw you can user viewstate for maintaining data as it is

Comment: @Ankit:Whose viewState Property may i will have use??Gridview Or RadioButton's View state Property????And  Can you Plaese explain viewstate property with example....Thanks...

Answer (score -1):

First I need to ask some questions that

why you don't want to do post back(Autopostback=True)?
if your answer is like "it is loading whole page again" then use "Update Panel"...